# Where is the implicit value for parameter P: cats.Parallel[cats.effect.IO,F]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Running the example code snippet under the subtopic [parSequence](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/io.html#parsequence) in Cats Effect document throws an error,

```
import cats._, cats.data._, cats.syntax.all._, cats.effect.IO

val anIO = IO(1)

val aLotOfIOs = NonEmptyList.of(anIO, anIO)
val ioOfList = aLotOfIOs.parSequence

<console>:44: error: could not find implicit value for parameter P: cats.Parallel[cats.effect.IO,F]
```

I include implicit `Timer[IO]` i.e. `implicit val timer = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)` but it *does not* work. Please advise. Thanks

## Update #1

For a complete working snippet,

```
import cats._, cats.data._, cats.syntax.all._, cats.effect.IO
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

implicit val contextShift = IO.contextShift(global)

val anIO = IO(1)
val aLotOfIOs = NonEmptyList.of(anIO, anIO)
val ioOfList = aLotOfIOs.parSequence
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit you're looking for is defined in `cats.effect.IOInstances` and you can bring it in scope by importing `cats.effect.IO._`.

```
private[effect] abstract class IOInstances extends IOLowPriorityInstances {
  //....

    implicit def ioParallel(implicit cs: ContextShift[IO]): Parallel[IO, IO.Par] =
    new Parallel[IO, IO.Par] {
      final override val applicative: Applicative[IO.Par] =
        parApplicative(cs)
      final override val monad: Monad[IO] =
        ioConcurrentEffect(cs)

      final override val sequential: ~>[IO.Par, IO] =
        new FunctionK[IO.Par, IO] { def apply[A](fa: IO.Par[A]): IO[A] = IO.Par.unwrap(fa) }
      final override val parallel: ~>[IO, IO.Par] =
        new FunctionK[IO, IO.Par] { def apply[A](fa: IO[A]): IO.Par[A] = IO.Par(fa) }
    }
}

object IO extends IOInstances {
  // ...
}
```

Note that you will need to have an implicit `ContextShift[IO]` in scope if you want to use the `ioParallel` instance.

It is a common pattern in Scala to have implicit instances defined as part of the companion object for the class (in this case `IO`).

Comment: The `ioParallel` is visible automatically because its inherited by the `IO` companion. No import needed. The likely issue is the lack of `ContextShift[IO]` in implicit scope.